# Stop execution of Activity if network is not availble - Android

Tags: android, networking, android-activity

In my Android App, user first lands on Login Activity. I am checking network availability. if network is not available, I want to stop the excision further.

Is is something we need to work on the code level or we have something available like `activity.cancel()` or `return null` on the Activity to process next code. Note that I do NOT want to close the Activity. I just want to alert the user that network is not available.

Here is the code:

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
    if ( v.getId() == R.id.btnLogin ) {

        if ( Utilities.isNetworkAvailable(this) ) {
            mIsNetworkAvailable = true;
        } 

        if ( mIsNetworkAvailable ) {
            username = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString().trim();
            password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString().trim();
        }

        // If U/P is empty, do NOT process anything, just display the alert and stop.
        if ( username.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
            Utilities.showAlert("Please enter username and password", this);

            // HOW TO STOP THE EXECUTION HERE
        } else if ( !mIsNetworkAvailable ) {
            Utilities.showAlert("Internet connection is not availble in your device.", this);
            // HOW TO STOP THE EXECUTION HERE
        }

        // If not any of the above, proceed.

        User userobj = new User();
        userobj.setUsername( username );
        userobj.setPassword( password );

        TaskHandler handler = new TaskHandler(getString(R.string.server_uri) + "Verify/", userobj, LoginActivity.this);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The above code is in onClick (Login Button). What I want to achieve is, when user clicks on Login button, if network is not available, I need to show the alert and stop further process. If its successful, I need to open the next activity.

This is regular flow like we do elsewhere. I know, we can wrap up the entire code in if-else block. But I am wondering, if there is a way to stop the execution with a call like `finish()`.

Note that, I do NOT want to destroy/close the activity. The activity should remain intact so user can keep trying, probably after turning on the network.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve from the code you've submitted. Can you please add more details.

Comment: Please check. I added more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just return if the constraint is not satisfied. Shown below...

```
.... .....
.... .....
if ( username.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
        Utilities.showAlert("Please enter username and password", this);

        return;
    } else if ( !mIsNetworkAvailable ) {
        Utilities.showAlert("Internet connection is not availble in your device.", this);
       return;
    }


    User userobj = new User();
    userobj.setUsername( username );
    userobj.setPassword( password );
.... .....
.... .....
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This code is in onClick method. And this method is void. So does not return anything. So I guess return won't work. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
finish();
```

which will terminate the activity in the context.

Comment: Does it close the app? or Activity? I want the activity to remain intact, so user can keep trying logging in.